# Print file name with comma separated in shell

Tags: shell, awk

I am printing name of files in directory but they are coming with space separated I want them to be comma separated. My file format is (publishfile.txt)

```
drwxrwx---+ h655201 supergroup 0 2019-04-24 09:16 /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample 
drwxrwx---+ h655201 supergroup 0 2019-04-24 09:16 /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample(1)
```

I want them to print like `sample, sample(1)`

My code for that is given below but it prints with space separated rather than comma separated

```
File=$(awk -F / '{ print $NF }' "$BASE_PATH/publishfile.txt") 
echo File
```

O/P I'm getting is

```
Sample Sample(1)
```

Comment: Please use CODE TAGS for your samples and codes as per forum rules. Kindly edit your post and let us know then, as it's not clear as of now.

Comment: Done the adding of code tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf`:

```
File=$(awk -F / '{ printf "%s, ", $NF }' "$BASE_PATH/publishfile.txt") 
echo $File
```

Comment: That's useless use of `echo` and one comma too many. Strictly speaking there's a quoting error, too.

Comment: Getting comma after last file also like sample, sample (1),